# How to skip null lines in java?

Tags: java, file, io

Hi I was looking to get some help with skipping **null** lines, I've searched for answers but im not able to find any. This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newest));
    String line = "";
    while (true) {
        if ((line = in.readLine()) == null) {
```

Comment: What do you mean by "null" lines? An empty line `""` or a line containing the word `"null"` or a line where readLine returns `null`?

Comment: A line that is blank and has no spaces a null line

Comment: I may be mistaken but `readLine` only returns `null` on the end of stream. In which case you can't simply "skip" it because there is no further input.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the code to look something like this:

```
String line;
while ((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
    if (!line.isEmpty()) {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

Normally I'd `trim` each line before checking if it is empty, but you say you want to exclude "a line that is blank and has no spaces", which implies you want to include lines that are just space.

If you *do* want to skip lines that are all whitespace, you could do this:

```
String line;
while ((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
    if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

The point of the `while` condition is that the `BufferedReader` will return `null` when the input is finished, so that should trigger the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Lines won't be null, they may just be empty. What I would do is check if it is empty:

```
if ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.trim();

    if (line.isEmpty()) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to first check for null, then call `trim()` on the line to remove white space, and then call `isEmpty()` to check if no text is present.

Comment: Shouldnt your first if statement be a while instead? If null is returned, the end of the stream has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

While reading from this stream, null will only be encountered at the end of the stream (file in this case). If you're looking for an empty/blank string, that test is within the loop (below).

Note that String.trim() does not trim the object itself, it returns the trimmed String. Equals method should generally be used to test for Object (such as String) equality.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newest));
String line = "";

//Line below keeps looping while the reader return a valid line of text.
//If the end of stream (file in this case) has been reached, you'll get null.
while ((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
    //line below tests for empty line
    if(line.trim().equals(""){

    }    
}
```